# Parse and filter http payload(egress) in tc bpf program

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, ebpf

I want to write an HTTP filter, which can filter requests according to path or header. In TC bpf program, the data in __sk_buff may contain multiple HTTP requests. If one of the requests matches successfully, it needs to be discarded, and the others need to be passed. Is this possible?
In sk_msg program, it can be solved by bpf_msg_cork_bytes() and bpf_msg_apply_bytes(), but these functions cannot be called in tc.

I want to be able to filter some requests and let some of it go